# Tapping TabBar crashes App

Tags: tabbar

I have a very strange error on my app. The App has two Tabs. Tab two shows a list of reports. If I tap one of the reports in Tab Two, the app correctly shows the details of the report. I then tap Tab one and immediately tap Tab two. The app crashes in iOS 8 but works fine for iOS 7.

If I returned to the root view controller of Tab two before tapping on Tab one, tapping Tab two again does not crash the app. Any idea what could be causing this error?

In the AppDelegate Class I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController *currentController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        [(UINavigationController *)currentController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I put an if statement to check if the phone is running iOS 8. The app has stopped crashing. Still not sure why the code crashes for iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the crashing by putting an if statement on the code as shown below. Still not sure why the code crashes in iOS 8.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    #define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
    {
        NSLog(@"The iOS is less than 8");

        UIViewController *currentController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            [(UINavigationController *)currentController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        return YES;
    }


    return YES;

}
```